# How to find out the source tcp port used by libcurl in a tcp session

Tags: c++, c, curl, tcp, libcurl

I developed a program in which I use a http client with libcurl.

I want to find out the source tcp port used by libcurl in a tcp session.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[curl_easy_getinfo](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) with the [CURLINFO_LOCALPORT](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html#CURLINFOLOCALPORT) option!